# crop image with fixed x/y ratio

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop

I want to crop image using following code. but i want to user only can select the crop area with a predefined x/y ratio.for example if x=2,y=2 ,then user can only use mouse to select an area with (x/y)=1 ratio.

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(I);
I2 = imcrop(I);
imshow(I), figure, imshow(I2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use imrect to produce the coordinates, and then pass those into imcrop.

```
figure, imshow(I);
h = imrect(gca,[10 10 100 100]); 
setFixedAspectRatio(h,1); % this fixes the aspect ratio; user can now change size/position
position = wait(h); % returns coordinates in "position" when user doubleclicks on rectangle
I2 = imcrop(I,position);
figure, imshow(I2);
```

In the actual code, you'll have to replace [10 10 100 100] with something of the appropriate size/aspect ratio for your images. You may want to add other constraints to imrect (for example to stop the user moving the rectangle outside the actual image).

Comment: setFixedAspectRatioMode is the correct function to fix the ratio. It took me a while to figure out what was wrong